# Who was Madhavi's mother?

Tags: mahabharata, vishwamitra, garuda

Emperor Yayati had [5 sons](https://bhagavata.org/canto9/chapter18.html#Text_29). From Devayani two sons Yadu and Turvasu, and from Sharmishtha three sons Druhyu, Anu and Puru . But he also had a daughter by name of Madhavi. Her story was given in [Udyog Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05115.htm), where Yayati gave her to Galava to help him fulfil Vishwamitra's guru dakshina of eight hundreed white steeds with one black ear. She beget three sons, Vasumanasa  from King Haryasva of Ishvaku dynasty, Pratardana from King Divodasa of Kashi, Sibi from King Ushinara of Bhoja dynasty.

All these kings desired to have sons from her given her beauty and proportionate body which was considered auspicious - six parts of this girl’s body which ought to be high are high, seven parts which ought to be slender are slender, three parts which ought to be deep are deep and five which ought to be red are red.

> unnateṣūnnatā ṣaṭsu; sūkṣmā sūkṣmeṣu saptasu; gambhīrā triṣu gambhīreṣv ; iyaṃ raktā ca pañcasu; śroṇyau lalāṭakakṣau ca ghrāṇaṃ ceti ṣaḍunnatam

Also she had the boon of regaining virginity after each delivery. These three kings had only two hundred steeds each which they gave Galava. When Garuda informed Galava that there is no scope for getting the remaining two hundred steeds as they don't exist, Galava took Madhavi and the six hundred steeds to Vishwamitra and requested him to have one child with her after which he (Galava) will take her back to Yayati. The reasoning being that he received two hundred steeds from each king for being able to bear a son with her. Vishwamitra was only pleased and said that had he known Galava had Madhavi he would have had four sons from her instead of eight hundred steeds. Through Madhavi, Vishwamitra was able to beget Ashtaka.

After Ashtaka's birth, Galava took Madhavi back to Yayati who then proceeded to take her on a swayamvara. However Madhavi rejected all suitors and retires to forest.

However I was unable to find any mention of Madhavi's birth or her mother. How did she acquire the boon to regain virginity after each delivery ?  Also if anyone can shed some more light on the specified auspicious signs (body parts) in Madhavi then that would be most helpful